# Laravel 4 syntax error out-of-the-box

Tags: php, syntax, yield, laravel

I just installed Laravel 4 (Illuminate) and as I opened the index.php file in a browser, I was met with this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'yield' (T_YIELD), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /www/Laravel4/vendor/illuminate/view/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php on line 339

I have fixed the permissions for the meta folder, and installed all the dependencies through Composer. I am running PHP version 5.5.0alpha2 on OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: FYI: I created a report in their issue tracker: https://github.com/illuminate/view/issues/23

Comment: FYI: The issue has been fixed, it's now PHP 5.5 compatible: https://github.com/illuminate/view/commit/d37abcecc7d79d00bf5f22b134d152ca765f26b2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `yield` became a language construct in PHP 5.5 (used in [Generators](http://nikic.github.com/2012/07/10/What-PHP-5-5-might-look-like.html#generators)) - but someone decided that it's a good idea to use this short word to name a function:

```
public function yield($section)
{
  return isset($this->sections[$section]) ? $this->sections[$section] : '';
}
```

Downgrade to PHP 5.4 (after all, it's the current mainstream version, 5.5 is not even in beta yet) and it should work fine.