# codeigniter bonfire php error after installing

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, netbeans, bonfire

I'm trying to install codeigniter bonfire. After clicking the install button on the create username screen, it takes a few moments and then it loads this page.  I watched some tutorials on how to install bonfire so I know this isn't what I should be seeing. [image: PHP error after installing]

Regardless, I updated the RewriteBase to /bonfire/ as it says..and now I'm getting this error when I try to go to localhost/bonfire/index.php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'yield' (T_YIELD), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/bonfire/bonfire/application/libraries/template.php
>   on line 305

Here's the code at line 305

```
public static function yield()
{
    $output = '';

    if (self::$debug) { echo 'Current View = '. self::$current_view; }

    self::load_view(self::$current_view, NULL, self::$ci->router->class .'/'. self::$ci->router->method, FALSE, $output);

    Events::trigger('after_page_render', $output);

    return $output;

}//end yield()
```

I found this link on bonfire forums explaining the error.
[Bonfire forums link](http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/1566/new-install-results-in-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-yield-t_yield/p1)

It says to use PHP 5.4 and that's what I'm using.  My operating system is Linux Zorin and I'm using lampp, so I'm not sure if this could be a permissions issue.
[image: php version]

thx in advance and please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but hopefully help.

You can change the name for static function yield in cibonfire, something like this:

```
public static function yield()
```

to:

```
public static function yield_content()
```

this works perfectly to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the LAMP the version of PHP is 5.5 + Something. IN PHP 5.5 there is a function name  as yield so you have to downgrade your LAMP PHP version to 5.4 or modify in the Bonfire file system.

For change in Bonfire You can Go through this link and your problem has been solved.

[https://github.com/illuminate/view/commit/d37abcecc7d79d00bf5f22b134d152ca765f26b2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990693/laravel-4-syntax-error-out-of-the-box)

You can also Review this link [Laravel 4 syntax error out-of-the-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990693/laravel-4-syntax-error-out-of-the-box)